# VS Code confirm on delete only on selected directories?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

VS Code allows one to control if deleting a file is preceded with a confirmation prompt.

`File>Preferences>Settings` (`explorer.confirmDelete`)
[image: Confirm Delete]:

Is there a way to control the scope of this? For example, the `hw` directory here should prompt on deletes except for the sub-directories, `tmp` & `exp`, should delete w/o the prompting.
[image]

Conceptually, the contents for `tmp` & `exp` are intended to be easily created at will, where as `src` is not intended to be disposed of w/o care.

Comment: and that's why I'm asking why you'd want to manually delete. How often do you have a real need to do that compared to just rebuilding? This is getting into extended discussion and I'm sorry I started derailing from the actual question. I'll delete my comments and we can talk in chat if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, no (though I'd be happy to be wrong now or in the future).

There are a couple things you can do:

- [Write a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) specifically for the `explorer.confirmDelete`- perhaps to support having an object as a value which maps from glob paths (like in `files.exclude`) to booleans.
- Seek some other method of easily deleting the files, such as writing a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), and then binding the task to a keybinding.
- If it works for your use-case, consider using workspace settings.json files (to set `explorer.confirmDelete` differently in each one) and splitting things using [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) (you can't get much granularity, and there are a lot of other implications of doing this that might make it not a good fit for your use-case)
- Check out https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111884 and the issue ticket it got closed as a duplicate of.